# first business day of next month

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to set the default value for a date parameter to the first business day of next month, that is if the 1st of the month is a Saturday or a Sunday, it selects the following Monday.
I've got this but for some reason when I try to run the report it says an error occurred during local report processing and I can't figure out what's going wrong. Can anyone help?

```
= iif (datepart("dw", dateadd("m",1,DateAdd("d",1-DatePart("d",Today()),Today()))) = 7,
dateadd("m",1,DateAdd("d",3-DatePart("d",Today()),Today())),
iif (datepart("dw", dateadd("m",1,DateAdd("d",1-DatePart("d",Today()),Today()))) = 1,
dateadd("m",1,DateAdd("d",2-DatePart("d",Today()),Today())),
dateadd("m",1,DateAdd("d",1-DatePart("d",Today()),Today()))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-Today.Day + 1).AddDays(
    SWITCH(
    Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-Today.Day + 1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday, 1,
    Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-Today.Day + 1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday, 2,
    True, 0
))
```

This returns the 1st of the following month:

```
Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-Today.Day + 1)
```

The switch statement then determines how many days to add based on the day of the 1st of the following month:

```
.AddDays(SWITCH(
        Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-Today.Day + 1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday, 1,
        Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-Today.Day + 1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday, 2,
        True, 0
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=Switch(
WeekDay(DateSerial(Today.Year,Today.Month,1).AddMonths(1),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)=6,
  DateSerial(Today.Year,Today.Month,1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(2),
WeekDay(DateSerial(Today.Year,Today.Month,1).AddMonths(1),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)=7,
  DateSerial(Today.Year,Today.Month,1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(1),
true, DateSerial(Today.Year,Today.Month,1).AddMonths(1)
)
```

Assuming your first date of week monday.

Hope it helps.